# Mysterious arithmetic function

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, volume, topological-groups

I have a function given by its Euler product
$$f(q) = \prod_{p^n || q} (1+p^{-2})p^{2n}$$

and I would like to see it as a convolution of standard arithmetic functions. In general, is there any method to "see" the answer easily, knowing for instance de Euler product of easier functions?

Comment: I'd write this as $f(q)=q^2\prod_{p\mid q}(1+p^{-2})$ and see if folding with $\mu$ or $\epsilon_0$ produces simplifications ...

Comment: Well, $f(q)=q^2\prod_{p\mid q}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p^4}\right)^{-1}$ and $f(p^k)=p^{2k}+p^{2k+2}$ give

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{f(n)}{n^s}=\prod_{p}\frac{1+p^{2}}{p^{s-2}-1}$$
which is convergent only for $s=4$ to $\frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)}=\frac{5}{2}$. It is unlikely such function can be written as a convolution of standard arithmetic functions: its Dirichlet series would be convergent on a larger set.